# Neo.ClientError.Transaction.ConcurrentRequest error on Neo4j

Tags: transactions, neo4j

What does this error means?

Neo.ClientError.Transaction.ConcurrentRequest

What does it mean to have concurrent requests using the same transaction? Do you mean multiple HTTP requests at the same time?

There is no documentation only the one given here: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/status-codes.html

I had an issue in which I was hitting that error in a single unit test.

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs:

Neo.ClientError.Transaction.ConcurrentRequest -> There were concurrent requests accessing the same transaction, which is not allowed.

Means you use the same transaction id in parallel requests, which is not possibles as transactions in Neo4j are thread-bound.

Comment: Within the REST interfaces, does this means that I am making parallel HTTP requests with the same transaction ID? Based on the code on https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/0abdabb9ac2d57dda45421d1f8b0ac8c7ece4755/community/server/src/main/java/org/neo4j/server/rest/transactional/TransactionHandle.java and https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/d92d3831def2ff5d7d1c68ad4fd22f45209642c7/community/server/src/main/java/org/neo4j/server/rest/transactional/TransactionHandleRegistry.java is what I conclude, however I am not completely sure (the release() and forget() mechanism).

Answer (score 1):

May be you are creating single connection object for parallel requests. If you create independent connection object it will work fine.

Check this thread: https://github.com/jakewins/neo4jdb-python/issues/10